# Using URLS in Django 2.0

Tags: python, django, url

I am learning to create REST API with Django and for demo purposes I tried to replicate and use the [tutorial given here.](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/05/11/creating-a-face-detection-api-with-python-and-opencv-in-just-5-minutes/).  I have created the project structure exactly as given in the tutorial.  The current directory structure is as follows:

```
cv_api
    cv_api
        __init__.py
        __pycache__
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wssgi.py
    face_detector
        admin.py
        apps.py
        __init__.py
       migrations
       models.py
       tests.py
       views.py
    db_sqlite3
    manage.py
```

I have included the codes for face detection inside `cv_api/cv_api/face_detector/views.py`.

I tried to edit `cv_api/cv_api/urls.py` to include the face_detector detect function as given in the tutorial.  The following is what suggested in the tutorial:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:

    url(r'^face_detection/detect/$', 'face_detector.views.detect'),

    # url(r'^$', 'cv_api.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

However, since i am using django 2.0.6 i realised that the patterns function is deprecated.  Hence, I tried to use the following:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('detect/',face_detector.views.detect),
]
```

But I am getting `face_detector not found` error when I run the `manage.py runserver`

Comment: seems you are not imported `face_detector` in `urls.py`

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Thank you...after adding `import face_detector` and from 'face_detector import views` runserver ran without a trouble...i can accept this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems you are not imported **`face_detector`** module  in **`urls.py`** :)